# how to post response data for instagram login page

Tags: authentication, instagram

I want to login on Instagram through a link or through an html form |
for example

```
https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/?enc_password=123&username=123
```

Hope I explained well

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the link and attribute:

```
www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/

enc_password=%23PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER%3A10%3A1632642160%3AATdQAL6Z9PWWJ2ocKoB5qT8Ew56%2Bs5FaGhyLKgaZUpIhFUgyWTyKqkG9IC5OK1d4qJ1KseE9cMjEbfiql0wh5mTpwM0Cw723JCexpS%2Fwm5lUucKh2g%2FEspMj9q5a%2BRtXsphCv%2FcLu2Bd7hS5

username=UserName
```

But POST method can't be in link directly, maybe you can do it with HTML this way:

```html
<form action="www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/" id="users"
            action="#" method="POST" target="_blank">
         
        USERNAME: <input type="text"  name="username"
                    placeholder="Enter USERNAME">
  
        <br><br>
         
        Password: <input type="password" name="enc_password"
                    placeholder="Enter Password">
         

         
        <br><br>
         
        <input type="submit" value="login">
  
    </form>
```